# restrict logs using log4j

Tags: java, log4j

I'm using log4j for logging, and it is the first time I'm working on it.

I want to log particular lines from the code, say for exmple

```
log.debug("this is my an example");
```

Only want these lines from my project in my log file. Is it possible using log4j?

Here is my log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, CA

log4j.appender.CA =org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.CA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CA.File=myLocation/logs.log
log4j.appender.CA.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.CA.Append=false
log4j.appender.CA.layout.ConversionPattern= %d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c - %m%n
```

aslo can we route the logging to separate file for each run?

Comment: Share your log4j.xml or log4j.properties file. Read more [log4j - Logging Levels](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_logging_levels.htm)

Comment: `ALL < DEBUG < INFO < WARN < ERROR < FATAL < OFF.` is the level in log4j. If DEBUG is enabled then all other type of logs that is higher in the hierarchy, are also logged in log file automatically.

Comment: You can specify log level based on package also.

Comment: @Braj Thanks for the comment, it really worked, I have included another question! please have a look

Answer (score 1):

Set `loglevel` in your code as below and make it as a static block or something where it should load at the startup

```
private static org.apache.log4j.Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LogClass.class);
log.setLevel(Level.Debug);
```

and for specific package restrictions of log, you can do like below

Suppose you have a package `a.b.c`

To specify logging level for this package as `debug`, add the below line in your `log4j.properties`

```
log4j.logger.a.b.c=debug
```

Comment: How to stop printing of other log levels in log file if used in same package?

Comment: You can make it though specifying the filter of certain appender.
Note: Filter is not supported by PropertiesConfigurator,so if you want to setup you log by file, just use XML instead.